# Incorrect roles on collective questions page

Tags: bug, status-planned, collectives

On the questions page for the [Google Cloud Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud?tab=questions&subtab=recentactivity&postFilter=SubCommunityQuestionPageFilter#sort-select), the "recognized member" role badge is inconsistently shown as part of the user's `.s-user-card-info`. The badge, as currently displayed in the questions list page, is *clearly* for the individual user, but doesn't actually reflect the user's status.

The issues are:

- It's shown in some cases when the user is not a recognized member of the Collective.
- It's not shown in some cases when the user is a recognized member of the Collective.

Currently, the badge appears to reflect the status of other people interacting with the post.

The display of this badge should be changed to accurately reflect the *user's* status as a member of the Collective. If it's desired that there be some indicator of interaction of other users with the question or answer, then that indicator should be located within the question's entry such that it clearly isn't associated with the specific user and should have a tooltip which describes what it's being used to indicate.

#### Investigation / details

In some cases, the badge won't show up even when the post was answer by a recognized member. In the following case, the badge should be next to Alex (also answer by a GCP member)

[image]

I did try [refreshing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iNdE.jpg) several times.

I am referring to the Questions page in [Google Cloud Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud?tab=questions&subtab=recentactivity&postFilter=SubCommunityQuestionPageFilter#sort-select).

**Edit:**

The following is another case where the user is not a "recognized member" but it still shows the orange recognized badge. This is the post: [Is there a way to display the fields of a Firestore Document with conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73678969/is-there-a-way-to-display-the-fields-of-a-firestore-document-with-conditions)

As seen in the previous screenshot, Alex is a recognized member but does not have the badge next to his name.

[image]

Comment: @Makyen I've updated the question with another case. It's like the mod badge shows up next to a person who is not a mod instead of yours.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I think the badge is shown as long as the question (not answers though) is by a recognized member or edited by one.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat that was my first thought. But doesn't happen always and as in the post the badge is missing when the post was actually edited by a recognized member.

Comment: @Dharmaraj in the [post in the first image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73672530/does-firestore-ttl-delete-documents-in-subcollections) the _question_ isn't edited by a recognized member the answer is.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat could be that. I had edited my _answer_ in post below that. The badge still shows up next to my name but I can see question was edited by recognized member. But not sure if that should reflect on the main questions list page. Also it just says "recognized member" and not "seen/edited by one"